# Swift protocol forcing the Equatable protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have define 2 protocols.
I need the first one (NameProtocol) to enforce the Equatable protocol.
While the other class (BuilderProtocol) have a method that return the first one (NameProtocol).

```
public protocol NameProtocol : Equatable {
    var name: String { get }
}

public protocol BuilderProtocol {
    func build() -> NameProtocol? // Compiler error
    init()
}
```

The compiler error : 
"Protocol 'NameProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

I need the object return by build() to return an object conforming to the NameProtocol and on which I can define ==

Is there a way I can make this work?

Thanks

---

If using a typealias in BuilderProtocol how can I make the array declaration work?

```
public protocol OtherRelatedProtocol {
    var allNames : Array<NameProtocol> { get }
}
```

---

**Conclusion**

I will remove the Equatable and implement an isEqual method.

```
public protocol NameProtocol {
    func isEqual(nameable: NameProtocol) -> Bool
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Comment: That error message is misleading (still in 3.0.2); it should read "*if* it has".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with Java or C#, Swift protocols are about halfway between generics and interfaces. One thing that you can do in a protocol, for instance, is this:

```
protocol Foo {
    func compareWith(foo: Self)
}
```

Classes that implement this protocol will have a method `compareWith` that accept an object *of their own type* (and not an object of type `Foo`).

This is what the compiler calls "Self or associated type requirements", and this is how Equatable is defined (it needs an `operator==` that accepts two `Self` operands). The downside of these protocols, though, is that you can only use them as generic constrains: you can't use them as an expression type.

The solution is to use generics. In this case, you'd make your `ProtocolBuilder` protocol generic, with a constraint that the type implements `NameProtocol`.

```
public protocol NameProtocol : Equatable {
    var name: String { get }
}

public protocol BuilderProtocol {
    typealias T: NameProtocol
    func build() -> T?
    init()
}
```

Comment: Which won't compile, because that isn't how you make a generic protocol.

Comment: Yes matt, I should have tested it.

Comment: Especially if you're just going to say what I already said in my comment. :)

Comment: Oh no! Okay, I'm deleting my comment and my answer, then. Drat.

Comment: No, my bad, I can't count and need to go to sleep. You were there first.

Comment: thanks, option 2 is leaving me with an other problem, I will update the question to show it.

Comment: @VinceBurn, associated type requirements in protocols are fairly viral. You may want to consider overloading the `==` and `!=` protocols without conforming to `Equatable`, or make your classes conform to it separately from `NameProtocol`, if you can't propagate generics through your whole code.

Comment: @zneak my goal is to have a framework that give object away, but I want the outside world to only know about protocols, because the exact classes might change, or in this case the protocol could be backed by a struct. But my goal is to keep the implementation detail internal to the framework and have the most flexibility I can get.

Comment: @VinceBurn, I don't think I can help you with that. I would probably settle for a base class. Are you sure that you need the flexibility of returning a struct instead of a class, though? Swift protocols do not hide the by-copy nature of struct values, so that seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I would maybe upgrade a struct to a class, but only immutable object.